# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read' music21 .show()

Tags: python-3.x, music21

> - i have been trying to show a score converted from krn file

```
import music21 as m
import os

test_data = "D:/Programming/DATA - SCIENCE/deep learning/music generation/data/test"
def load_krn_files(data_path):
# go through the whole files 
songs = []
for path , subdirs,files in os.walk(data_path):
        for file in files :
            if file [-3:] == "krn":
                song = m.converter.parse(os.path.join(path,file))
                songs.append(song)
return songs

def preproccessing(data_path):
    pass
    #1 ) load the kern files and pars them
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    songs = load_krn_files(test_data)
    print(f"loaded {len(songs)} songs.")
    song = songs[0]
    song.show()
```

> - but the method (show) return the following error
>
> loaded 12 songs.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "d:/Programming/DATA - SCIENCE/deep learning/music generation/scripts/preprocess.py", line 25, in 
> song.show()
> File "C:\Users\ae504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\music21\stream\base.py", line 334, in show
> return super().show(fmt=fmt, app=app, **keywords)  File "C:\Users\ae504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\music21\base.py", line 2788, in show
> return formatWriter.show(self,
> File "C:\Users\ae504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\music21\converter\subConverters.py", line 1114, in show
> self.launch(returnedFilePath, fmt=fmt, app=app)
> File "C:\Users\ae504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\music21\converter\subConverters.py", line 197, in launch
> subprocess.run(cmd, check=False, shell=shell)
> File "C:\Users\ae504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\run_*init*_.py", line 145, in **new**
> process = cls.create_process(command, stdin, cwd=cwd, env=env, shell=shell)
> File "C:\Users\ae504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\run_*init*_.py", line 121, in create_process
> shlex.split(command),
> File "C:\Users\ae504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shlex.py", line 311, in split
> return list(lex)
> File "C:\Users\ae504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shlex.py", line 300, in **next**
> token = self.get_token()
> File "C:\Users\ae504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shlex.py", line 109, in get_token
> raw = self.read_token()
> File "C:\Users\ae504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shlex.py", line 140, in read_token
> nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: What version of music21 are you using?```import music21; music21.__version__```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.